# SWT tree > move the vertical scrollbar to the left of the tree without changing the orientation

Tags: java, tree, swt, scrollbar

How to put the vertical scroll bar on the left hand side of the tree?

[image]

Comment: imho, that would be very unexpected to end-user

Comment: The scroll bar cutting through the connection lines to the right side in this example is uncomfortable. 
anyways, question is, can it even be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows only, you could do this:

```
int exStyle = OS.GetWindowLong(tree.handle, OS.GWL_EXSTYLE);
exStyle |= OS.WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR;
OS.SetWindowLong(tree.handle, OS.GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle);
```

Otherwise you might want to look into [Snippet296](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet296.java), which shows how to handle scrolling for a Tree using a ScrolledComposite. By adding the style SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT to ScrolledComposite, and SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT to the Tree in this snippet, I had a scroll bar on the left. But I failed to fix the positioning issue of the Tree, which comes up then.

Comment: thanks a lot!!

I also tried something similiar to the snippet before (using a slider) and it's just too "shaky". couldn't get much further with the snippet either 

the windows flag works perfect and that's enough for now.