# SWT Tree: draw line from label to the right side

Tags: swt, treeviewer

I'm working on a similar application like the figure in this question:
[SWT tree > move the verticle scrollbar to the left of the tree without changing the orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228323/swt-tree-move-the-verticle-scrollbar-to-the-left-of-the-tree-without-changing-t)
I don't know how to draw the connection lines like the figure.
My naive solution is that I add a lot of "-" to the label and it ends up like this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCKU7.png!

Moreover, I want to add the dotted line to indicate the child-parent relationship. Here is a similar question http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t82430.html but with no solution.

Comment: I have found a promising solution at http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to the above question: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html