# Designing a specific layout

Tags: java, layout, swt

I need to create a layout that looks like the one in the picture but I'm lost.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't undo my edit, it's better.

Comment: You might want to start with some of the java layout tutorials. [This one](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) seems to be pretty good.

Comment: @drew_w For links in comments: [the link](the addressX where X is ).

Comment: Off topic: Can you have display text for links in comments? I'm new to answering so I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: @drew_w Yes, `[myText](myLink)`.

Comment: @drew_w Please read the tags properly, this isn't about Swing...

Comment: @user3061943 Please let us know what you tried so far including your current code. We aren't just going to code it for you, you know? Reading this might help: [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html)

Comment: i know you wont do this for me,
i just didn't know where i can find tutorials that show what i need to do.
Thank you for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you a starting point:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    Composite contentHolder = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    contentHolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    contentHolder.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    createMenuBar(shell);
    createContent(contentHolder);

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(600, 400);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}

private static void createContent(Composite parent)
{
    Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("connect");
    button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    canvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
}

private static void createMenuBar(final Shell shell)
{
    Menu menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
    MenuItem fileItem = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
    fileItem.setText("File");
    MenuItem helpItem = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
    helpItem.setText("Action");

    Menu fileMenu = new Menu(menuBar);
    fileItem.setMenu(fileMenu);
    MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem(fileMenu, SWT.NONE);
    exitItem.setText("Exit");

    Menu aboutMenu = new Menu(menuBar);
    helpItem.setMenu(aboutMenu);
    MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem(aboutMenu, SWT.NONE);
    aboutItem.setText("Some action");

    shell.setMenuBar(menuBar);
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

If you really need the vertical scrollbar on the left, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228323/swt-tree-move-the-verticle-scrollbar-to-the-left-of-the-tree-without-changing).